# Recursive problems in 2D array C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a problem that from a certain number 1 in a 2D matrix with (x, y) coordinates. From this number, it will start spreading out its 4-neighbor which their values will be assigned by (start point + 1)

We start from a coordinate of (3, 3) = 1. Its neighbor's value will be 2. Next step, 4 neighbors of the point having value of 2 will be 3. And so on, until, all 1 numbers in the matrix are infected!

I have resolved this problem by using some loops. However, I'd like to resolve it by another way that is recursion. But I haven't done with it.

Before

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

After spreading out

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 2 3 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 1 2 3 4 5 0 0
0 0 3 2 3 4 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 4 5 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 5 6 0 0 0 0
0 0 8 7 6 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 9 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Below is my code but I just can spread all 1 numbers with another value but not as I want. So please help me resolve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 10

using namespace std;

int data[MAX][MAX] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
};

int mark[MAX][MAX];


void spreading(int x, int y, int v){
    if (x < 0 || x == MAX) return;
    if (y < 0 || y == MAX) return;

    if(data[x][y] == 0 || mark[x][y] != 0)
        return;
    data[x][y] = v;
    mark[x][y] = v;

    spreading(x + 1, y, v);
    spreading(x, y + 1, v);
    spreading(x - 1, y, v);
    spreading(x, y - 1, v);
}

void printArr(int a[MAX][MAX]){

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; ++j) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    spreading(3, 3, 1);
    printArr(data);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you want a recursive solution? This one is probably better.

Comment: @Beta sounds a bit like coursework.

Comment: Yes. This is my coursework and I have recently learned about Recursion. So I want to resolve it with recursive solution. It's just I want to improve my programming skill with recursion.

Comment: 2 points: 1) v is always 1 and you are assigning (not adding) v in the array, so you can never have more than 1 in the array (unlike your original result) if v is constant, do you need it as parameter? ; 2) I'm not sure if order is essential, but you are first always incrementing x until finished before incrementing/decremeting y.  Is this as expected?

Comment: Looking again at the original result, I would suspect that the order of incrementing (my point 2) is okay, so passing v+1 to spreading() should be okay, as answered by Jarod42

Comment: @stefaanv: `v + 1` is not enough, as the order **is** important. My solution is not optimal (visit some case several time).

Comment: @Jarod42: yeah, I saw you updated your answer for a better return check.  I hadn't checked that, since it was only a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Following may solve your issue: (https://ideone.com/VQmBhU)

```
void spreading(int x, int y, int v){
    // Test if x, y is inside the propagation area
    if (x < 0 || x == MAX) return;
    if (y < 0 || y == MAX) return;
    if (data[x][y] == 0) return;

    // if already visited with a better path, cancel.
    // if not visited, or the previous visit was worst than this try, continue
    if (mark[x][y] != 0 && mark[x][y] <= v) return;

    data[x][y] = v;
    mark[x][y] = v;

    spreading(x + 1, y, v + 1);
    spreading(x, y + 1, v + 1);
    spreading(x - 1, y, v + 1);
    spreading(x, y - 1, v + 1);
}
```

Some example of 're' visit (with the `mark` array content):

```
(1) 0  ->   1 (2)   -> 1  2  ->  1  2
 0  0       0  0       0 (3)    (4) 3
```

`1 <= 5`, `3 <= 5` : (4) finished
`2 <= 4` : (3) finished
`1 <= 3` : (2) finished
`4 > 2`  : we continue propagation from (1)

```
(1) 2  ->   1  2
 4  3      (2) 3
```

...

Comment: I appreciate your solution but can you tell me more detail about a condition: if (mark[x][y] != 0 && mark[x][y] <= v) return;

Comment: As we do a [Depth-first_search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), some visited case will have higher value than expected. when we visit these node later, we really want to update these node if we have a shorter path, but if our path is longer, we don't want to propagate any more.